# Why are all my Remix test accounts showing 0 ETH?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix, ether

I'm trying to write a TicTacToe game on remix.ethereum.org but all of a sudden all my test accounts show 0 ETH balance, so I can't use them to deploy my contracts anymore.

Here is the solidity code that I was deploying when it happened:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract TicTacToe {

    uint8 public boardSize = 3;

    address[3][3] board;

    address public player1;
    address public player2;

    constructor() public {
        player1 = msg.sender;
    }

    function joinGame() public {
        assert(player2 == address(0));
        player2 = msg.sender;
    }

    function setStone(uint8 x, uint8 y) public {
        board[x][y] = msg.sender;
    }

}
```

New test accounts still show 100 ETH upon creation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is anything to do with deploying your Solidity code.

What blockchain environment are you using? It is most likely a problem there.

[Remix environment menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mStY2.png)